# Are questions about TVs off topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

About 2 hours ago, the question [Why do enormous TVs take longer to turn on than smaller TVs?](https://superuser.com/questions/363573/why-do-enormous-tvs-take-longer-to-turn-on-than-smaller-tvs) got closed for being off topic.

The question also has a comment that reads

> TVs are not computer software or hardware and as such are offtopic as per the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq). The fact that you use them to display power point slides does not make a question regarding the TVs on topic.

I cannot agree with either.

1. TVs can clearly interface with a computer and the FAQ regards devices that *interface with your computer* as on topic.
2. The OP is actually using the TV as a monitor.
3. I doubt anyone would classify a question about monitors as off topic and a TV is basically a monitor with a tuner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the question was about how to get the TV to connect up with the computer then it would be on topic. If it was about how to use the TV as a fifth monitor to their existing setup, that too would be on topic.

That question is neither of those.

It's about the television as a standalone item. It's a consumer electronic product, but not a computer. And it isn't about interfacing with the computer either.

It's the same as asking why your static discharge socks used when fixing a computer feel better when you turn them inside out.

Answer: Because the seams aren't cutting into your toenails and the terry towelling is on the outside now.

Comment: Makes sense. Just to clarify: What if the same question was asked about computer monitors?

Comment: If it's as good and as well written and as researched as the one about CPU start times, yes http://superuser.com/questions/360363/why-does-my-pc-successfully-boot-only-when-unplugged-for-more-than-a-few-minutes

Comment: @Dennis While you could pose the same question about computer monitors and it may be slightly more on-topic as it is now about hardware that can only be used on computers I would still vote to close for the exact same reason:  it is not actually a computer-based problem but rather one of electronic component manufacture and thus is off-topic.  If the OP had asked if slow turning on was a sign of some problem with the computer or monitor then I would consider it vaguely on-topic but as it was it isn't and I don't.

Comment: @random: I agree that the question was not a very good one. +1 for the discharge socks analogy alone.